# \titlespacing + scrreprt not working

Tags: spacing

I am currently trying to change the titlespacing after a \subsection*{}.
Tried

```
\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]{\large\bfseries}{\thesubsection\quad}{0pt}{}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{6pt}{2pt}
```

But changing the value to 2pt isn't working. Just has no effect at all.
Packages in use:

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
```

Would be glad for any hints to a solution. Not a latex pro here, but still trying to learn =)

Comment: Welcome! You may increase your chances of getting a useful answer by posting a minimal working example (MWE). This may help: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that

Comment: The usage of `titlesec` and any of the KOMA classes (`scrreprt`) is **not** recommended.

Answer (score 2):

Note, that the usage of `titlesec` together with a KOMA-Script class is not recommended. With an up to date KOMA-Script version (current version on CTAN is 3.17a) you can use instead

```
\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=6pt,afterskip=2pt]{subsection}
\renewcommand*\subsectionformat{\thesubsection\quad}
\setkomafont{subsection}{\normalfont\large\bfseries}
```

Example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}[2015/05/06]

\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=6pt,afterskip=2pt]{subsection}
\renewcommand*\subsectionformat{\thesubsection\autodot\quad}
\setkomafont{subsection}{\normalfont\large\bfseries}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter One}
\KOMAScriptVersion{} is used.
\section{Section One}
\blindtext
\subsection{Subsection One}
\blindtext
\subsection*{Subsection with Star}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

---

If you still use version 3.15 or 3.16 add the following lines before the redefinition of `\subsectionformat`:

```
\renewcommand*\othersectionlevelsformat[3]{#3\autodot%
  \ifstr{#1}{subsection}{\quad}{\enskip}% change the space only for subsection
}
\providecommand*\subsectionformat{}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for that. I am currently using Koma 3.12 apparently. That explains why I couldn't use the examples I found.